# GMap3 not working in

Tags: google-maps, maps, jquery-gmap3

please do somebody know why (jQuery)Gmap3 in not showing map if request is coming from Kosovo? Even demos on their official site are not working.
Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/E28X2lvjmbs while having a look, not sure if it's related or not?

As well as: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/W9JRmDSGSTE

Looks like there have been some issues with Kosovo for a while even though I believe Google has recently recognized it as a country within it's maps?

Comment: Thanks for answer and i know about the reverse geocoding problem in kosovo but i'm not 100% sure that it is related. Because normal google maps are working in kosovo... only map by gmap3 not...